# Brown spots on my Fiddle Fig plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-recommendations, plant-care

I've just noticed these brown areas on my plant today when I've arrived from work. I had moved this plant from my bathroom window which had given my plant indirect sunlight to my livingroom window where there is direct sunlight. I've left it there for about 3 days straight. I don't want to loose this plant as I've had it since it was very small. Will my plant survive? Should I cut the brown foilage off? I'm not sure what to do or what happened to it. Will my plant survive?

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

UPDATE: 
[image: 1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will my plant survive?

Yes, but you may wish to consider cutting back the stem to a 6 or 12 inch length to encourage new growth.

Should I cut the brown foliage off?

Too early to say, this looks like sunscald when moving from indirect to direct light.  If the brown area turns brown and dry then you can remove the leaf for aesthetic purposes.

[Ficus lyrata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_lyrata) is a tough plant but the leaves are hard and take a while for each one to grow.

Look for scale (brown bumps) or mealybug (white cottony tufts) on the underside of the leaves but this does not seem likely from the description you gave.

Cutting it back is a good solution as it keeps the plant smaller and encourages new growth.

You have asked about where to cut on the stem to encourage new growth.  Wait and see if the leaves with brown spots continue to die back. If they do, remove the leave at the stem and cut the stem back with a sharp sequitur to six or twelve inches from the base of the plant.  If this means no leaves, no problems!  The plant will bud out from the cut and grow new leaves.

Comment: The last 2 leaves at the bottom turned completely brown and hard. So it was easy to take them off from the stem. I did cut about 6 inches off, which left me with 3 leaves. As you said; this is fine. Thank you for responding to my additional question :)